# Having problems setting a value to a choice field

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am trying to use iText 7 to populate pdf forms programmatically. I use C# libraries. everything goes well so but choice fields. When a value is set for the field it becomes kinder highlighted in the resulting pdf. looks like this:

[image]

this does not happen to other types of fields. I am using `PdfFormField.SetValue(string value)` function. I tried to cast type to `PdfChoiceFormField` with the same result.

Any help?

PS here is the [form](https://sqforms.blob.core.windows.net/templates/11?st=2017-10-10T16%3A09%3A00Z&se=2017-10-17T16%3A09%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2016-05-31&sr=b&sig=KQd%2BnmR9DS7i812g4JjSTcf%2FyyJ6JnijLM1DKgsO0Os%3D).

PPS One more observation: I understand that iText is not changing background randomly (and not supposed to :) but here are values of the instance before and right after `field.SetValue("California")`.

[image: values differences]

Comment: Please share the original PDF form. iText 7 does *not* randomly change background and text color. If the color is changed, either those colors are defined in the form, or *you* are changing them.

Comment: I've added the link to the form. the field for example is "7. State/Country of Birth". Thank you!

Comment: One more observation: I understand that iText is not changing background randomly (and not supposed to :) but here are values of the instance before and right after `field.SetValue("California")`. Adding image to the main question...

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of a choice field you need to use the `SetListSelected`method like this:

```cs
string value = "hello world!";

if (ff is PdfChoiceFormField ch)
{
    ch.SetListSelected(new[] { value });
}
else
{
    ff.SetValue(value);
}
```

Of course `value` should be one of the value allowed by the Choice field.